# Reshape with factors

Tags: r, reshape

I am trying to reshape a data frame that contains a factor and a numeric variable with the melt and cast procedure. The following data shows my problem:

```
library(reshape)

df <- as.data.frame(cbind(c(1,1,2,2,3,3),c(2000,2001,2001,2002,2000,2001),c(2,1,4,3,1,5)))   
names(df) <- c("Id","Year","Var")

df$Fac <- interaction(c(1,1,1,0,0,0),c(0,0,0,1,1,1),drop=TRUE)

MData <- melt.data.frame(df,id=c("Year","Id"))
RSData <- cast(MData, Id ~ Year | ...)
```

The operation works, but the missing observations in RSData are not NAs as they should be, but rather strings (< NA> and not NA):

```
$Var
  Id 2000 2001 2002
1  1    2    1 <NA>
2  2 <NA>    4    3
3  3    1    5 <NA>

$Fac
  Id 2000 2001 2002
1  1  1.0  1.0 <NA>
2  2 <NA>  1.0  0.1
3  3  0.1  0.1 <NA>
```

If I, however, disregard the factor the NAs are normal NAs:

```
df <- as.data.frame(cbind(c(1,1,2,2,3,3),c(2000,2001,2001,2002,2000,2001),c(2,1,4,3,1,5)))   
names(df) <- c("Id","Year","Var")

MData <- melt.data.frame(df,id=c("Year","Id"))
RSData <- cast(MData, Id ~ Year | ...)
```

The output becomes:

```
$Var
  Id 2000 2001 2002
1  1    1    1   NA
2  2   NA    1    0
3  3    0    0   NA
```

The string NAs give me problems when I try to use my recast data. How do I get the correct NAs when I have a factor and numeric variables in the data frame I want to melt and recast?

Thanks,

M

Comment: Are Dummy1 and Dummy2 supposed to be numeric or factors? You trouble begins with the variable `Fac` which is a factor, but is melted into the numeric variables Dummy1 and Dummy2.

Comment: @joran So, they two variables 'Dummy1' and 'Dummy2' are numeric, but only take on 0 and 1. I want to combine these into a factor, 'Fac'. I know that in this small example making a new factor doesn't make a lot of sense, but in my real data, I have several dummies and thus get more than 2 levels in the resulting factor.

Comment: But the larger issue here is that when you _melt_ the df, R is trying to stack Fac on top of all the Dummy variables. In doing so, it has to find a single, common data type to use. Even if they are all factors, you are going to run into trouble merging factor levels. Are you sure you mean to include the Dummy variables when melting?

Comment: I can see that the same thing happens when I have a column in my data frame where the entries are of type `character`. I guess, I have to keep the dummy variables, and avoid factors, and do my analysis with all the dummy variables and not have one single factor - cumbersome but possible.

Comment: Well, there is probably a better way to go about this. But it's hard to say what that would be without more details. But keep in mind that your original strategy of melting the df to have a _single_ factor variable with values from Dummy1,..., _and_ their interaction was fundamentally nonsensical. That's the part I was trying to get clarification on, because that's the part that makes no sense.

Comment: @joran Ahh, that makes sense. The dummy variables are not important to me, but in my real data, I have other numeric data that I would like to melt. Is there a a simple way to do melt the numeric variables together and the factor by itself, and then combine them after they have been cast?

Comment: The obvious option would be to subset the data frame you pass to melt so as to exclude the dummy variables.

Comment: @joran: But let us say I exclude the dummy variables but have other numeric data that I want to melt along with my factor. How can I do this?

Comment: Why would you ever want a single column with values from both numeric and factor variables? Don't do that.

Comment: @joran: I understand that having both numeric and factor variables in one column is bad. But that is not my goal. My goal is to recast the data, so that it's ordered by year. I have changed the question a bit.

Comment: @JackRyan: The solution should have NA's and not <NA>'s for the missing numeric values. I could just as well use `reshape2`, but old habits die hard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am confident that I have found the answer to my own question by reading the comments and the documentation over and over. Bascially, the problem is that when using the melt.data.frame() method all the variable values are put in 1 column, and since I have both strings and numeric values the numeric values are implicitly converted to strings.

The only way around this I see is to reshape the numeric variables and the factors separately:

```
MDataNum = melt.data.frame(df[c("Id","Year","Var")],id=c("Year","Id"))
RSDataNum <- cast(MDataNum, Id ~ Year | ...)

MDataFac = melt.data.frame(df[c("Id","Year","Fac")],id=c("Year","Id"))
RSDataFac <- cast(MDataFac, Id ~ Year | ...)
```

The result becomes:

```
> RSDataNum 
$Var
  Id 2000 2001 2002
1  1    2    1   NA
2  2   NA    4    3
3  3    1    5   NA

> RSDataFac 
$Fac
  Id 2000 2001 2002
1  1  1.0  1.0 <NA>
2  2 <NA>  1.0  0.1
3  3  0.1  0.1 <NA>
```